# Executing python autogui script on ssh remote executes commands on ssh host

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x, ssh, subprocess

I am trying to execute my python script over ssh on my Pi. I have setup my Priv/Pub Keys and execute them by using a python script on my host machine:

`subprocess.run('ssh -p 2222 john@<IP_of_Pi> python3 /home/john/test.py', shell=True)`

I am trying to automate some things by using autogui. My basic script looks like this

```
import pyautogui as aut

aut.PAUSE = 1
aut.keyDown('ctrl')
aut.keyDown('alt')
aut.press('t')
aut.keyUp('alt')
aut.keyUp('ctrl')
aut.typewrite(['f','i','r','e','f','o','x','enter'])
aut.hotkey('alt','d')
aut.typewrite(['d','u','c','k','d','u','c','k','g','o','.','c','o','m','enter'])
```

My problem here ist that all commands I execute are run on my local host machine. Same goes if I use other automation frameworks, e.g. Selenium. Every browser I open up is not started on my Pi, but on my host machine.

I have tried several modifications of subprocess, like

```
subprocess.run(['ssh','-p','2222 ','john@<IP_of_Pi>', 'python3', /home/john/test.py'])
subprocess.run(['ssh','-p','2222 ','john@<IP_of_Pi>', 'python3', /home/john/test.py'],shell=True,stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
subprocess.Popen(['ssh','-p','2222 ','john@<IP_of_Pi>', 'python3', /home/john/test.py'])
...
```

I can reprocude the errors if I execute `test.py` in my shell, the browser still opens on my host.

Just in case its relecant, the ssh_config on my remote (Pi):

```
Host *
#   ForwardAgent no
#   ForwardX11 no
#   ForwardX11Trusted yes
#   PasswordAuthentication yes
#   HostbasedAuthentication no
#   GSSAPIAuthentication no
#   GSSAPIDelegateCredentials no
#   GSSAPIKeyExchange no
#   GSSAPITrustDNS no
#   BatchMode no
#   CheckHostIP yes
#   AddressFamily any
#   ConnectTimeout 0
#   StrictHostKeyChecking ask
#   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
#   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_dsa
#   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_ecdsa
#   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_ed25519
#   Port 22
#   Protocol 2
#   Ciphers aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc
#   MACs hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com
#   EscapeChar ~
#   Tunnel no
#   TunnelDevice any:any
#   PermitLocalCommand no
#   VisualHostKey no
#   ProxyCommand ssh -q -W %h:%p gateway.example.com
#   RekeyLimit 1G 1h
    SendEnv LANG LC_*
    HashKnownHosts yes
    GSSAPIAuthentication yes
```

Comment: 127.0.0.1 is localhost, thus your machine... I don't undestand you question...

Comment: Its just a dummy ip, i modified the question